# Showing Object on Gaze Unity

Tags: c#, hololens

I have this hit information when gazed upon an object. The object appears when gazed on, but disappears when looking away. I want the object to show 10 seconds after looked on. Am I on the right path?

```
float timeLeft = 10.0f;
timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
if (Hit == InfoCube)
{
    GameObject.Find("GUIv2").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.2f, 0.8f) // Shows object
}
else if (timeLeft < 0)
{
    GameObject.Find("GUIv2").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    GameObject.Find("GUIv2").SetActive(false);                    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this code placed? I assume it's in the Update() method.

In any case I can see some problems with the code. Here are my suggestions:

1. Cache the "GUIv2" object so you don't have to "find" it every frame.
2. You don't need to change the localScale value. Just use SetActive.
3. Don't initialize the `timeLeft` variable every time. It will never reach 0.

Here's some sample code that should achieve what you're looking for:

```
    float timeLeft = 10f;
    bool isGazed;
    GameObject GUIv2;
    void Start()
    {
        GUIv2 = GameObject.Find("GUIv2");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Hit == InfoCube)
        {
            if (!isGazed)
            {
                // first frame where gaze was detected.
                isGazed = true;
                GUIv2.SetActive(true);
            }
            // Gaze on object.
            return;
        }
        if (Hit != InfoCube && isGazed)
        {
            // first frame where gaze was lost.
            isGazed = false;
            timeLeft = 10f;
            return;
        }

        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            GUIv2.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```